# IIS 7.5 Win2k8 R2 - redirect not working

Tags: iis-7.5, redirect

we have a server that has an app pool setup in IIS.
We got an external URL registered to point to the default login page of the app on this server.
Problem is if I remove redirect in IIS, the external URL points to the default IIS startup page on the server.
If I enable redirect the external URL infinitely tries to resolve the target URL and then just ends of with server page not found.
Please advise where I am going wrong. I tried reading through the TechNet articles and few stack overflow pages for solution which has not helped me so far. Thanks in advance!